# jQuery: “Tokenizing” autosuggest plugin allowing the adding of new items

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, tokenize

I'm looking for a “Facebook style” or “tokenizing” autosuggest plugin for jQuery allowing multiple selections from the suggested list as well as new entries.

**This plugin does exactly what I need**, but it requires Mootools as it seems: http://devthought.com/projects/mootools/textboxlist/

The known plugins for jQuery out there seem to be either not allowing new entries (which are not on the list of suggestions) or are only tokenizing e.g. email addresses but don't have any autosuggest functionality.

Here's what I had looked at so far:

- https://github.com/sbfaulkner/jquery.token-field (no autosuggest)
- http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/ (no new entries)
- http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbkcomplete.html (no new entries)
- http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin (no new entries)

Did I miss one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Drew Wilson's autoSuggest does allow for adding new tokens. I got to use it -- well, not exactly itself, rather a saner fork of it: https://github.com/alanhogan/AutoSuggest -- which brings us to the major problem with this thing: it's not maintained properly. Neither did I like a funny (generated) input field which gets the results nor an apparent inability to restrict entering new tokens.

Comment: Thanks for the hint — I'll check it out!

Comment: You're absolutely right — not sure how I had missed this update. I find the usage of the tab key a little unintuitive in this context, but the plugin fulfills my criteria. Cheers!

Comment: I agree with these limitations of an otherwise beautiful implementation. I actually need it to prevent tokens and am not sure how to make it do that.

Answer (score 0):

I was also thinking of using this plugin http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/

The only disadvantage is that it relies on jQuery-UI, which adds an additional library just to support the that small feature. If you're already using jQuery-UI already is not a big deal.

Comment: Looks interesting! I actually ended up using a rewrite of the plugin by Drew Wilson (http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin) which can be found here: http://jsbin.com/asahe5/10